# Is there a way to have a semi-transparent element "cancel out" or mask an element behind it?

Tags: html, css, layout, transparency, navigationbar

I've customized a [CSS Menu Maker](http://cssmenumaker.com/) dropdown for my site:

[image]

But as you can see, the shadow of the "banner" shows through the background of the dropdown.

**How do I make it so the shadow isn't there when behind the dropdown?**

Of course, it depends on how it's all constructed, so:

- The "banner" is actually a 8px-wide transparent PNG strip, background-ed with `repeat-x`. (It has a transparent gradient so that the photo slideshow behind it smoothly fades at top.)

  [image]
- On top of that is the CSS Menu Maker dropdown—just unordered lists, anchors, and span, styled as `inline-block` and such. I can paste the code if needed but it's nothing out of the ordinary.

At first I created an alternate 8px "strip" without the shadow, but I can't think of a way to substitute it in the `repeat-x` only where the dropdown is.

Now, I'm thinking the shadow itself should be a separate PNG, but I still can't figure out how I'd make it invisible (*e.g.* `visible: hidden;`) only when behind the dropdown.

Comment: A little off-topic, but instead of using a repeating image for the header background, you can use a semi-transparent `background-color` (with `rgba()`) with a `box-shadow`

Comment: @JonathanLam - Is there a way to do a gradient transparency? I wasn't aware of any such way, so I went with a PNG.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a complex js function. Split the shadow into its own image. Js triggers on hover and measures the left and right position of the drop-down. Js then positions two elements using absolute positioning either side of the drop-down with shadow as the background image. Sounds like a nightmare to me